# Unable to run Py File as Batch .BAT file

Tags: python, batch-file

My code works fine when it's .py but when I make it an executable .bat file and run it, it shows a module not found error. Really stumped and not sure what's causing this behavior.

I've tried pip installing or updating a bunch of the modules and it hasn't had any impact.

Here's the error I am receiving:

```
File "C:*****\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 155, in read_pickle
    return pickle.load(f)
  File "C:*****\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries
  File "C:*****\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pyproj
  File "C:*****\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from pyproj._datadir import PYPROJ_CONTEXT
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Here is a copy of the batch file.

```
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\GeoPandas_DS\python.exe"
"C:*****/Python/Py_Script.py" pause
```

**EDIT SOLUTION**

Just had to activate the proper environment. Below batch file worked.

```
call activate [your_env_name]
"C:\Users\Path_To_Python_File\Py_File.py"
pause
```

Comment: Do you mean that you wrote a batch file to run the .py script and packaged it into an executable with an .exe extension. Or did you just change a .py extension to .bat, then package it to an .exe?

Comment: I wrote a batch file to run the .py script. I created a notepad text file with the following, then saved it as .bat "Path where your Python exe is stored\python.exe" "Path where your Python script is stored\script name.py"
pause

Comment: When you package batch files as .exe files, they're invariably unpacked to a temporary location and ran from there. Your batch file and/or python script would therefore have to account for the scripts different/unknown current directory or use fully qualified paths.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean. The first line of the script is setting the directory already, so I am not sure that's the issue.

Comment: Join the club! _... as you're the only person who can see the exact content of the batch or python scripts and the system/environment._

Comment: Please [edit] you question and add a copy of the batch file you're using.

Comment: added batch file

Comment: Could it have something to do with activating the conda environment? How would I do that in batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is probably the conda environment activation in your batch file.

```
call activate [your_env_name]
python your_script_name.py
call conda deactivate
```

Comment: This makes sense and I think is right solution, but I am having trouble getting the final touches on the batch file. Edited question. I want it to be able to run in the activated environment and keep the cmd window open while running ideally.

Comment: Got it. This is the right solution, with minor modifications. Added solution to question. Thanks!